# Как в метод отправить одно значение вместо нескольких?

Tags: java

Суть вопроса такова. Например есть метод:`frame.setBounds(1,1,1,1);`
он устанавливает размеры окна. Как в этот метод вместо 1,1,1,1 написать например массив или объект содержащий эти единицы. Или это невозможно без добавления перегрузок?

Comment: если метод `setBounds` не ваш и в библиотеке не предусмотрена перегрузка, то без добавления собственного метода не обойтись

Comment: Напишите свой метод, который будет принимать то, что Вам нужно и вызывать frame.setBounds(1,1,1,1);

Answer (score 0):

Если Вас не устраивают метода класса то как вариант можно создать новый класс с более удобными для вызова методами. А старый класс будет внутри.
Например:

```
public class TFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(new JFrame("Tests"));
        MyPoint point = new MyPoint(10,10);
        MySizes mySizes = new MySizes(200,100);
        frame.setBounds(point, mySizes).setVisible(true);
    }
}


class MyFrame {
    private JFrame origin;

    public MyFrame(JFrame originFrame){
        origin = originFrame;
        origin.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JFrame getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public MyFrame setBounds(MyPoint point, MySizes sizes){
         origin.setBounds(point.getX(),point.getY(),sizes.getWidth(),sizes.getHeight());
        return this;
    }

    public MyFrame setVisible(boolean b){
        origin.setVisible(b);
       return this;
   }

}

class MyPoint{

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public MyPoint (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

class MySizes{
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public MySizes (int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```